# What's the pattern to $\frac12(m+1)(2n+3m)$ for positive $n$, $m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

This is derived from $S_a=\sum_{i=0}^m(n+ai)=\frac12(m+1)(2n+am)$, $(n,m)\ge1$ when $a=3$

A number that works is some number where some $n,m$ Plugged into $S_a$ will result in that number. So $[n,m]=[1,2]$ plugged into $S_1=6$, so 6 works for $S_1$

Note: if $a=1$, $S_1$ can be every number that is not a power of $2$, and will never be a power of $2$. If $a=2$, $S_2$ can be every composite number but never a prime.

I found that for the same reasons $S_1$ can never be a power of $2$, $S_3$ can never be a power of $2$

I also found that $S_3$ can be every odd number greater than $4$($5$ being the smallest number $S_3$ can ever be) because $(n)+n+3=2n+3$, which if n is positive, will generate every odd number greater than $4$.

I also found that the numbers generated by $S_3=\{5+2x\}\cup\{12+3x\}\cup\{22+4x\}\cup\{35+5x\}\cup\cdots\cup\{\frac12(3k^2-k)+kx\}\cup\cdots$, $x=\{0,1,2,3,\cdots\}$

I then used that to find numbers that didn't work: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ebklyzijdy $S_3\ne1,2,3,4,6,8,10,14,16,20,28,32,44,52,64,68,76,88,104,128,136,152,184,208,232,248,256,272,296,304,328,344,368,464,496,512,592,656,688,736,752,848,928,944,976,992,1024,1072,1136,1168,1184,1264,1312,1328,1376,1424,\cdots$

I do see a pattern though. Only primes times powers of $2$ don't work, for instance $496=2^4\cdot31$, $1376=2^5\cdot43$.

So that's where I am in finding the pattern. I think it may have to do with every number with $2$ odd factors working but I don't know.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. You ask for a pattern for an already closed formula, and talk about numbers that 'work' or 'do not work' but never specify what exactly makes something work or not. Do you mean to ask if there is a simple classification whether or not a number $x$ can be represented as $\frac{1}{2}(m+1)(2n+3m)$ for some $n, m$?

Comment: @orlp, I added a paragraph (second one) that should make it better

Comment: Have you tried fixing $m$ then iterating $n$ from 1 to 10 and putting results into an OEIS search?

Comment: @Mr.Brooks, I plugged in the numbers that couldn't be written in the form, and that gave me a good result, Thanks for the suggestion, though, if I fixed either $m$ or $n$, it would result in a polynomial

Answer (score 3):

First let's properly define $S_a$:$$S_a=\left \{ x \mid (\exists n,m \in \mathbb{N}) \left [x = \frac12(m+1)(2n+am) \right] \right \}$$

We are interested in the set $S_3$. I will separate the numbers into two classes based on the parity of $m$.

1. Say that $m$ is even. Let's write $m = 2k$. Then we can write our expression as $\frac12(2k+1)(2n+6k) = (2k+1)(3k+n)$.
2. Say that $m$ is odd. Let's write $m = 2k+1$. Then we can write our expression as $\frac12(2k+2)(2n+6k+3) = (k+1)(2n+6k+3)$.

What can we conclude from this? Well in case one $2k+1$ is a factor, and in case 2 $2n+6k+3$ is a factor, both of which are always odd. Therefore we can conclude that in all cases any $x \in S3$ must contain an odd factor. In other words, powers of two can't occur, and that observation of yours is correct.

When $k = 0$, case one is impossible (because then we'd have $m = 0$), but we see that case two simply becomes $2n + 3$. So every odd number $\geq 5$ is in $S_3$.

The only category of numbers left to explore is those of the form $2^s \cdot d$ with $d$ odd. In fact, I will factor further and write $x = 2^s \cdot p \cdot r$ where $p$ is the smallest odd factor of $x$, and $r$ is odd (and may be $1$).

1. $(2k+1)(3k+n) = 2^s\cdot p\cdot r$. To maximize the amount of numbers for which this is valid we find that $2k+1 = p$ and $3k+n = 2^s\cdot r$. This is possible when $3k < 2^s\cdot r$, and thus $p < \frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^s\cdot r + 1$ is the criterion for case one that allows the most numbers.
2. $(k+1)(2n+6k+3) = 2^s\cdot p\cdot r$. Here the most permissive strategy is to set $k+1 = 2^s$, and $2n + 6k + 3 = p\cdot r$. This is possible if $6k + 3 < p\cdot r$, which simplifies to $\frac{6\cdot 2^s - 3}{r} < p$.

Combining both cases we find that any number where

$$p < \frac{2}{3} \cdot 2^s \cdot r + 1 \quad \vee\quad \frac{6\cdot 2^s - 3}{r} < p $$

is in $S_3$ (in addition to any odd number $\geq 5$). Using DeMorgan's law we can invert this so find the criterion for numbers **not** in $S_3$:

$$\frac{2}{3} \cdot 2^s \cdot r + 1 \leq p \leq \frac{6\cdot 2^s - 3}{r}$$

But  if $r \neq 1$ this inequality is impossible, thus we can conclude that $p$ is the *only* prime factor of $d$. Thus the only numbers bigger than $5$ not in $S_3$ (in addition to the powers of two) are those of the form $p \cdot 2^s$ where $p$ is prime and $s \geq 1$ and

$$\frac{2}{3} \cdot 2^s + 1 \leq p \leq 6\cdot 2^s - 3$$

Comment: Yet 1763=41*43=880+883 and in fact every odd number greater than 4 works(.5n-1.5,.5n+1.5) so your logic is messed up somewhere, not sure where.

Comment: @JacobClaassen:  I don't see how you get $1763$.  We then need $(m+1)(2n+3m)=3526=2\cdot 41 \cdot 43$ but one factor is three times greater than the other and we can't satisfy it.

Comment: @JacobClaassen If you have a counterexample then please give me a $m, n$ to plug into $\frac{1}{2}(m+1)(2n + 3m)$ to get $1763$. It's not possible. I have no idea where you got $880$, $883$ from or why you're adding them.

Comment: @orlp, $m=1, n=880$, if $m=1$, every odd number can be generated. And this problem stems from adding integers that are $3$ apart, so $7+10+13$, look at the first line of my question and you'll see that

Comment: @RossMillikan, if $m=1$, it cancels out with the $\frac12$, leaving $2n+3$

Comment: @JacobClaassen The crucial error in my answer was that once $m = 2k+1$ I assumed that $k$ can't be 0, which is not true. I have updated my answer with a strict criterion.